# retrofit + GSON doesn't serialise HashMap, GSON on his own does

Tags: android, rest, gson, retrofit

My request model contains map and looks like

```
public class AddRequest {
public String url;
public String key;
public Map<String, String> attributes;

public AddProductToBasketRequest(String url, String key, Map<String, String> attributes) {
    this.url = url;
    this.key = key;
    this.attributes = attributes;
}
```

}

when I'm printing my model by

```
new Gson().toJson(request)
```

I've got

```
{"url":"https://www.net-a-porter.com/lalala","attributes":{"size":"it34"},"key":"agtzfnNm"}
```

but when I'm sending request by retrofit, I've got empty attributes in logs

```
{"attributes": {}, "url": "https://www.net-a-porter.com/lalala", "key": "agtzfnNm"}
```

My RestAdapter looks like

```
public RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Access-Token", token;
            }
        })
        .setEndpoint(url)
        .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new GsonBuilder()
                .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.FINAL, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.STATIC)
                .serializeNulls()
                .create()))
        .build();
```

Code that do the request looks like

```
AddInterface restInterface = restAdapter.create(AddInterface.class);
restInterface.request(id, request, new Callback<Basket>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Basket basket, Response r) {
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of not "sending correctly"? What exactly happens?

Comment: Hey Jerry, I checked with backend dev and I'm sending empty map. I edited my question.

Comment: what is the code that makes the request like?

Comment: njzk2 I updated my question and it contains that code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was just clearing a HashMap in another part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want to send from a POST request

```
{"url":"https://www.net-a-porter.com/lalala","attributes":{"size":"it34"},"key":"agtzfnNm"}
```

you should try this :

```
public class AddRequest {
public String url;
public String key;
public Attributes attributes;

public AddProductToBasketRequest(String url, String key, Attributes attributes) {
    this.url = url;
    this.key = key;
    this.attributes = attributes;
}

public class Attributes {
    protected String size;

    // getter & setter
}
```

Because {} should be a object and [] a List

Comment: Attributes can be whatever like: "attributes":{"size":"it34", "color":"blue", "colour":"green"}